# how to animate image through angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, angular-animations

The half way  it should go up  and at the same time to the right  and the second half way also to the right but now go down , instead of go up
Also i tried a variant with the keyframes, but it doesn't help,

```
    export const ShowBall = trigger("ShowBall", [
      state('2', style({ top: '300px', left: "100px" })),
      state('1', style({ top: '300px', left: "300px" })),

      transition('1 <=> 2',

        group([
          animate('2s'),
          sequence([
            animate('1s', style({ top: '200px' })),
            animate('1s', style({ top: '300px' }))
          ]
          ),
        ])
      ),
    ])
```